# Finding Stationary Paths of a System

Tags: calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, euler-lagrange-equation

I am working with the below functional

$S[y]=\alpha y(1)^2+ \int_0^1dx \beta y'^2, \:\:y'(0)=0$

with a natural boundary condition at $x=1$ and the constraint

$C[y] =\gamma y(1)^2 + \int_0^1dx w(x)y^2=1$,

where $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are constants.  The task is to show that the stationary paths satisfy an Euler-Lagrange equation

$\beta \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + \lambda w(x) y=0, \:\:y(0)=0,(\alpha-\gamma \lambda)y(1) + \beta y'(1)=0$,

where $\lambda$ is a Lagrange multiplier.  I then have to let $w(x)=1$ and $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=1$ and find the non-trivial stationary paths of this system, along with the eigenfunctions and the values for the associated Lagrange multiplier.  Is anyone able to guide me through the process on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auxiliary functional is:
$$\bar{S}[y] =(\alpha -\lambda\gamma)y(1)^2+\int_0^1(\beta y'^2-\lambda\omega(x)y^2 dx$$
Now determine: $\bar{S}[y+\epsilon h]$, with $y(0)=0$
Then the Gateaux differential becomes:
$$\triangle \bar{S}[y,h] = 2(\alpha -\lambda\gamma)y(1) h(1) +2 \int_0^1(\beta y'h'-\lambda\omega(x)y)h dx$$
Now integration by parts gives:$$\triangle \bar{S}[y,h] = 2(\alpha -\lambda\gamma)y(1) h(1) + 2\beta y'(1)h(1)-2\int_0^1(\beta y''+\lambda\omega(x)y)h$$
Since $h(0)=0$. On a stationary path $\triangle \bar{S}[y,h]=0$ for all allowed h. Now for $h(1)=0$ as a subset use the fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations to obtain:
$$\beta \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\lambda\omega(x)y=0$$
Then on a stationary path $2(\alpha -\lambda\gamma)y(1) + \beta y'(1)h(1)=0$ and this must be true for all h, including those for which $h(1) \neq 0$, hence we also need:
$$(\alpha -\lambda\gamma)y(1) + \beta y'(1)= 0$$
which is required in your question.

Comment: I didn't expand $S[y+\epsilon h]$ because it is quite standard. If you' ve any difficulties in it, let me know.

Comment: @Tom: my answer doesn't suite your wishes? Please let me know how to improve it.

Comment: I guess you submitted your TMA answer without rewarding this contribution

Comment: @ Joe Goldiamond: I've been asked to look at this question, I don't do the course though! can you briefly explain why the equations for euler lagrange don't work  here,and why we use the  gateaux differential?

Comment: The EL are not suitable overhere due to the first part of the functional. I.e. $(\alpha -\lambda \gamma) y(1)^2$. You can’t apply the EL eq.

Comment: why is that though? could I not just put the constant in the integral?

Comment: No in that case you change the question. See Richards, Chapter 2 and 3.

Comment: have you taken this course? I've looked at the course notes I've been sent but I'm missing any examples like the above one and why e l does not work. do you specific pages or examples I should look at to explain why we can't have a constant inside the integral?thanks.